# Как можно сделать перекодировку символов вывода printf юникод в cp866?

Tags: c, avr

Как можно стандартными средствами библиотек cb сделать перекодировку символов вывода printf в cp866 ?

Comment: Мне нужно выводить в консоль данные в формате cp 866.

Comment: Мне не надо setlocal.

Comment: Ваш код работает на микроконтроллере?

Comment: да работает на мк. Нужно поменять кодировку вывода printf.

Comment: @zhilenkov А что у вас доступно? Т.е. есть какая то Unicode строка в виде байт (например закодированная по 4 байта UTF-32) и нужно её сконвертировать в CP866 в виде байт перед подачей в printf? Или в обратном направлении то же самое?

Comment: Так проще не грузить контроллер перекодировкой, а исходники хранить в cp866.

Comment: Или напишите функцию перекодировки по [таблице](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu-data/blob/master/charset/data/xml/windows-866-2000.xml)

Comment: @gbg Я предлагал... Ответ - см. самый первый комментарий автора: *Мне нужно выводить в консоль данные в формате cp 866*. Понимай, как знаешь. Еще раз попытался пояснить - после чего отчаялся донести свою мысль, и убрал свои комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно выводить в консоль данные в формате cp 866.

Не понятно. У Вас есть (к примеру) текстовый файл в кодировке cp866 и вам надо выдать его на консоль в кодировке utf8 ? Или наоборот - вохд в utf-8 а на консоль Вы хотите писать в cp866 ?

Вы не указали ОС, под которой будет работать Ваша программа. Но, не думаю, что на AVR работает Windows. Поэтому:

```
ICONV(3)                          Руководство программиста Linux                          ICONV(3)

ИМЯ
       iconv - изменяет кодировку символов

ОБЗОР
       #include <iconv.h>

       size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
                    char **inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
                    char **outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);

ОПИСАНИЕ
       Функция   iconv()   преобразует   последовательность   символов   с   одной  кодировкой   в
       последовательность символов с другой  кодировкой.  Аргумент  cd  должен  быть  дескриптором
       преобразования,  созданным ранее с помощью функции iconv_open(3); дескриптор преобразования
       определяет кодировки символов, которые  iconv()  использует  для  преобразования.  Аргумент
       inbuf   содержит   адрес   переменной,   которая   указывает   на   первый  символ  входной
       последовательности; в inbytesleft содержится количество байт в  этом  буфере.  В  аргументе
       outbuf  содержится  адрес  переменной, которая указывает на первый байт выходного буфера; в
       outbytesleft содержится количество байт в выходном буфере.
```